# Canot identify the issue ionic2 with visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ionic2

I would like to build my Visual Studio ionic2 app and receive the error below.
Did anyone meet this issue?
The app works fine with ionic serve but VS does not build it.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(387,5): error MSB6006: "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.
1>       Done executing task "VsTsc" -- FAILED.
1>     1>
1>Done building target "CompileTypeScript" in project "MyIonic2Project.jsproj" -- FAILED.
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and the latest ionic2: 2.0.0-rc.1

Comment: Did you do a web search for the error code?

Comment: Sure, no useful results

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update the typescript extension for visual studio